# Loading Radiobutton from sqlite table

Tags: android

Is it possible to load radiobuttons/radiogroup straight from a sqlite table?  That is, the code to generate a radiobutton/radiogroup is loaded from a sqlite column. 
I'm attempting to load this information from the database table directly into a ListView. So a user can scroll through a list view and click radio buttons inside each ListView

Comment: There's nothing that's already built for you. You have to design your own scheme for storing and reading the data and generating the necessary radio buttons yourself. You don't need a layout file to build a layout; you can create Views and add them to a ViewGroup programmatically (e.g. with `new` and with `addView()`).

Answer (score 0):

for that you can create **custom listview** and in to that handle it's onclick for appropriate outcome.

Useful this link to learn custom list view:
http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview